# Getting File from /res/raw

Tags: android

I need your help, may be this question is very easy for you.
I have a file in /res/raw folder. For example, it's id is **R.raw.myFile**. I need to get "File" object. Such as i can do with file on sdcard

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/myFolder/myFile");
```

How I can do this?

By the way, sorry for my english if there are some mistakes.

I need "File" object. Not stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);
```

Comment: Indeed i found the same answer just by searching stackoverflow.

Comment: This is *not* what he wanted